# How can I quickly place assets on a grid?

Tags: workflow, random

I'm currently learning Blender and have taken on a personal project of building a city to keep pushing myself. I'm currently designing generic buildings and other assets of varying sizes and shapes to fill out the city. Before I get too deep into that, I'd like to know:

1. Is there a way to automatically fill out a grid with random buildings without overlap?
2. Alternatively, a fast and easy method of placing them on the grid from my asset library. (Preferably just have it snap to a vertex and rotate it appropriately)
3. Anything I could do to the asset files themselves to streamline the process.

Here's a bit of the grid I've got right now: [image: A hexagonal surface with some triangular grids drawn on it]

And here are the work-in-progress buildings: [image: A collection of gray box buildings of varying sizes and shapes made to fit on the triangular grid]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3.) & 2.):
To manage your assets have a look at Blender's [Asset Browser](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/asset_browser.html). There are plenty of tutorials on YouTube. When dragging and dropping assets from the Asset Browser Blender already snaps them to your drop target based on the bounding box of the asset. Additionally, starting from Blender 4.0, [snapping tools](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/snapping.html) got a huge upgrade with the possibility to choose a "snap base" (lots of tutorials on YouTube for this, the documentation is not very clear currently).

1.) That sounds like a case for Geometry Nodes to me. I recommend taking a look at tutorials on the subject of `Instance on Points`, `Mesh To Points`, `Realize Instances`, `Transform Geometry`, `Translate Instances`.